# cypress-keycloak-commands using on keycloak login

Tags: authentication, cypress, keycloak

I try to use cypress-keycloak-commands in my tests but always get this error:
[image]

I did everything accorig to this docu: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-keycloak-commands

I don't understand how the code should know where to fill in the username an password. This is my code for the login:

```
  it('Login', () => {
  cy.visit(Cypress.env('GBS_URL'))
  cy.kcLogout();
  cy.kcLogin("user");
  cy.visit("/"); })
```

What is the probleme here? I changed the user.json to my setings, added the env: { ... } to the json abd installed the package. Also added:`import "cypress-keycloak-commands";` in the commands.js file.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the keycloak library, and it's expecting to find a `<form>` element, but not finding it.

This is the piece of code where the error occurs.

```js
    const authBaseUrl = Cypress.env("auth_base_url");
    const realm = Cypress.env("auth_realm");
    const client_id = Cypress.env("auth_client_id");

    cy.request({
      url: `${authBaseUrl}/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/auth`,
      followRedirect: false,
      qs: {
        scope: "openid",
        response_type: "code",
        approval_prompt: "auto",
        redirect_uri: Cypress.config("baseUrl"),
        client_id
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        const html = document.createElement("html");
        html.innerHTML = response.body;

        const form = html.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
        const url = form.action;
```

The form should be part of the `response.body`, but since it's not there the request must be failing.

Check what you have in `Cypress.env("auth_base_url")`, `Cypress.env("auth_realm")` and `Cypress.env("auth_client_id")`

If you added them to `cypress.json` they would be similar to this

Ref [Setup Keycloak configuration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-keycloak-commands#setup-keycloak-configuration)

> Setup the Keycloak configuration in cypress.json configuration file:
>
> ```js
>  {
>    "env": {
>      "auth_base_url": "https://auth.server/auth",
>      "auth_realm": "my_realm",
>      "auth_client_id": "my_client_id"
>    }
>  }
> ```

Comment: I added the "env" to the cypress.json and changed all the vairables according to our system but i still get the error. How do you mean it expects a <form> element. With cypress i selected the input fields and entered the username and password. How does this work here??

Comment: You can see it in both the error message and in the code I posted. `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading action)` Check the highlighted line, it has `form.action` so therefore form is the thing that's undefined. And form comes from `getElementsByTagName("form")` which is getting an element with the tag name <form> (sort of explains itself).

Comment: There's still something wrong with you setup, try copying the code above into a test and putting a `console.log(response.body)` to see what you are getting back.

Comment: I had the same problem until I realized that the `/auth` suffix was missing in my `auth_base_url`.